# Remove b' from value in Python 3

Tags: python

Trying to remove the b' from output

```
word_site = "http://link.de/prox.txt"
response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()
print (random.choice(WORDS))

Prints b'116.11.254.37:80'
```

When I try

```
word_site = "http://link.de/prox.txt"
response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()
print (WORDS.decode('utf-8'))


print (random.choice(WORDS))
```

the output is:

```
    print (WORDS.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

What am I doing wrong? The .txt link simply has lines of proxies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

splitlines returns a list, you have to operate on each element of the list

```
word_site = "http://link.de/prox.txt"
response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()
utf8_words = [w.decode('utf-8') for w in WORDS]
print (utf8_words)


print (random.choice(utf8_words))
```

Better Yet (from megalng):

```
word_site = "http://link.de/prox.txt"
response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.decode('utf-8').splitlines()
print (WORDS)


print (random.choice(WORDS))
```